# Couldn't validate XSD SAML metadata file

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, saml-2.0, xml-validation

In SAML 2.0 , I took the metadata XSD file from 
http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd

And I am trying to validate the XML against its XSD from the above location using the online tool http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VFjicMntid1. It is showing error on the XSD file itself. What is the problem with the XSD file?  How can I validate my own SAML metadata XML against its XSD for validation?

Here is the image of the error I am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you just pasted your XML on the left side and the [`saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd) on the right side [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/)?

In this case the problem is, apparenty that this validator could not resolve the relative import:

```
<import
    namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    schemaLocation="saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd"/>
```

Which is absolutely understandable. Online validation tools may be suitable for "quick and dirty" validation but are generally not suitable for more complex cases.

Take a look at [this collection of SAML tools](http://www.coreblox.com/2011/06/collection-of-useful-saml-tools/), you might find something useful there.

Validating SAML XML against the XSD is only a part of the SAML assertion validation (a completely optional part, if you ask me). The mandatory part is to validate the signatur which has nothing to do with XSD.

Comment: Above link is changes to https://www.coreblox.com/blog/2011/06/collection-of-useful-saml-tools